# Using AssignMessage policy to generate a formatted string in Apigee

Tags: apigee

I am doing a URL rewrite in my API End point. So, the querystring is not passed by default to the backend service.

I want to create a variable with name "querystring" and format that string with the input query params. How can I do that?

For eg: apigee api url = https://myapigee-prod.agigee.net/v1/test/resource1?p1=abc&p2=123

I want to create the querystring variable as querystring = param1=abc&param2=123

I tried

```
<AssignVariable>
    <Name>myqs</Name>
    <Value>param1={request.queryparam.p1}&amp;param2={request.queryparam.p2}</Value>
</AssignVariable>
```

`<Ref>` tag can be used instead of `<Value>` tag only if I am getting value of one parameter. To form a string, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use the curly braces method of variable expansion within an AssignVariable.

You can do this via a JavaScript policy. Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var myqs = "param1=" + context.getVariable("request.queryparam.p1") +
    "&param2=" + context.getVariable("request.queryparam.p2");
context.setVariable("myqs", myqs);
```

Comment: This probably is the most viable option. I can prepare the querystring names in the assign message policy and use the javascript to form querystrting url

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use an AssignMessage policy to do this, on the Proxy request or Target request flow.

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/generate-or-modify-messages-using-assignmessage

e.g.

```
<AssignMessage name="GenerateRequest">
<AssignTo createNew="false" type="request">Request</AssignTo>
<Set>
<QueryParams>
  <QueryParam name="p1">{request.queryparam.param1}</QueryParam>
  <QueryParam name="p2">{request.queryparam.param2}</QueryParam>
</QueryParams>
</Set>
</AssignMessage>
```

Comment: This one helps too. But, its just that, I will have to create one assign message policy per resource in the target request flow.

Comment: If [this is you](https://www.linkedin.com/in/ikqureshi), then you should disclose your affiliation in your answers and probably also in your user profile.